# Как сделать динамические padding у пунктов меню в nav?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, flexbox

Имеется следующий код:

```
<nav>
      <div class="wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <div id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
                    <div><a href="sale.html">Sale</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Handbag</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Wallets</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Accessories</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Mens Store</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Shoes</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Vintage</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#">Services</a></div>
                    <div id="contact_us"><a href="contact.html" target="_blank">Contact us</a></div>
                </ul>
       </div>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Bebas Neue, sans-serif;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    color: white;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 66%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
    background-color: #3bc3b6;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 1.4em;
}

nav ul div {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 8px 0;
}

nav ul div a {
    border-right: 2px solid white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 1.1vw;
}

#home a {
    padding-left: 0;
}

#contact_us a {
    padding-right: 0;
    border-right: none;
}

nav ul div a:hover {
    color: #1e90ff;
}
```

Как сделать динамические padding у пунктов меню в nav (nav ul div a), то есть сжимающиеся при уменьшении окна браузера?
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MzMYJV

Comment: Я не проверял но можно попробовать указать padding в vw или vh

Comment: Тоже думал на этот счет, как и насчет процентов и em. Кроме того, не обойтись без media queries

Comment: Я видел рекомендации к этому же вопросу на toster и разумется что медиа запросы ...про vw  vh если постараться то будут работать и без запросов